# Replace single " (quotation mark)

Tags: java, string, replaceall

How can I replace a single quotation mark `"` in a `String` in Java? Not the word inside a quote.

Comment: What did you try? Are you asking how to put a `"` in a string?

Comment: string = string.replaceAll(""", "");

Comment: Try \" adding \ would treat (") as a character and not the default interpretation of compiler.

Comment: @AadilKeshwani backslash not foward slash ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String s = someotherstring.replace("\"",""); // replace all occurrences of "
```

Comment: (Replace the "" with whatever you want to replace with

Comment: unnecessarily using pattern compiling, as long your replacement is not a `String`. Use String#replace(char, char) instead.

Comment: @jp-jee the replace string isn't guaranteed to be one character only, why is this unnecessary?

Comment: As I said, _as long your replacement is not a String_.

Comment: @jp-jee did you down vote the answer? I find this as an acceptable answer because it provides more uses than String#replace(char,char) and answers the question. You don't expect me to know about their preferences do you?

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as an argument to [String#replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-).

Example: To replace any `"`by an `x`, use:

```
 myString.replace('"', 'x');
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhh!!!! Don't you need an escape?

Comment: Why would I? No opening/closing quotes would be disturbed. It's a `char`. Perfectly working.

Comment: Sorry you're right XD